# Move query results to another location

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

I have a Airflow DAG defined in the python file. Would like to run a query against the bigquery public data localized in the US and store the result in my biquery in EU location. Would be great to manage the operation in a one DAG step.

Use a code like below, but it throws an error: set a location to US, but the output dataset is in another location.

```
get_data = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
  ...
  location='US',
  sql="""
    select ...
    from 'bigquery-public-data.new_tork_taxi_trips.tlc_green_trips_2018'''
  """,
  destination_dataset_table=<my-proj>.<my-dataset>.<my-table>,
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to `Temporary and permanent tables` on BigQuery documentations, when you write query results to a permanent table, **the tables you're querying must be in the same location as the dataset that contains the destination table.**

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#limitations_on_copying_tables

Comment: Yes, it is a solution. Is it possible to query results in US, store result as temporary table and than write another step to use temporary table already created and store results in EU? Would be great to avoid materializing data twice.